# Get new comments of facebook post (since parameter)

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-comments

I am trying to get comment of a fanpage since a given time. But it seems like the since parameter is ignored.

```
try {
    $attachments = array('access_token' => $profile['access_token'], 'since' => strtotime('2013-03-07T18:13:57+0000'));
    $comments = $facebook->api("$id/comments", 'GET', $attachments);
    print_r($comments);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
}
```

Isn´t that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `since` doesn't work with every table. A solution is to use FQL:

```
SELECT id, time, text 
  FROM comment
 WHERE object_id = POST_ID
       AND time > UNIX_TIME 
 LIMIT 50 
OFFSET 0
```

(replace `POST_ID` and `UNIX_TIME`)

---

You can loop on this query while incrementing the `OFFSET` by 50.

The first group will give the 50 most recent comments, the second the 50 previous and so on. But each group contains comments ordered in **chronological** order.

You can stop looping once a query sends less than 50 results.

Comment: Salut Stéphane. Thanks for you´re answer. Yes, this is what I wanted to do alternatively. But then I faced this problem: [FQL Table returns Anonymous User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303387/facebook-fql-comment-username-anonymous-user)

Comment: De rien. I've already seen your other post but I couldn't find an explanation yet. Anyway, that's another problem. Finally, did I help you to solve your first problem: to get the post comments **since** a given time?

Comment: Ok! Found a solution to your second problem.