# Facebook FQL comment username = anonymous user

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-fql

When quering the FQL comment table like this:

```
SELECT post_fbid, fromid, username, time, text FROM comment WHERE post_id = id
```

I am getting the results but username for every comment is "Anonymous User". Does anyone know why this is happening and has a solution maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **username** The user name that a user entered when they posted a comment.
>   In these cases, the fromid returned will be 0. Note that user names
>   for valid users are not returned here.

I honestly don't understand what this `username` exactly represents but you can simply ignore it!

The `fromid` gives the ID of the commenter. From that, there is no problem for you to get the user name!

The `ID` can either be the one of a user or a page. I made a multiquery for you that gathers all the information you need:

```
{
"comments": "SELECT post_fbid, fromid, time, text FROM comment WHERE post_id=\"205861559433343_336511733034991\"", 
"users": "SELECT uid, username FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT fromid FROM #comments)",
"pages": "SELECT page_id, name FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT fromid FROM #comments)"
}
```

Comment: Hi Stéphane. Thanks, I didn´t found this paragraph in the docs or just didn´t noticed it. This is the way I am doing it now too. But I wondered about the returned anonymous user. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The `username` field only contains data if you are using the Facebook Comments plugin on an external site. People may leave comments without being logged into Facebook. This field reflects data that the user entered when they left the comment.

Otherwise, as Stephane mentions, you need to use the `fromid` field and resolve this to the actual user.

I would query the `profile` table to get this, as it returns the owner of any ID, whether it be a page, group or user:

```
{
"comments": "SELECT post_fbid, fromid, time, text FROM comment WHERE post_id=\"205861559433343_336511733034991\"", 
"commenters": "SELECT id, username, name FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT fromid FROM #comments)"
}
```

Comment: Hi cpliko. I am sure that the usernames ar given. When getting the comments via graph api method /post-id/comments the names are returned correctly. But thanks for pointing out to use the profile table!